# Prevent Apache CXF from dumping PDF contents in logs

Tags: logging, cxf

I am using the Apache CXF library, version 2.7.7. My problem is that the default logging feature dumps PDF files' raw contents. I would prefer for PDF contents to be logged as "--- Binary Content ---", just like other binary content.

I have configured CXF logging by adding these lines to my Spring context.

```
<cxf:bus>
    <cxf:features>
        <cxf:logging/>
    </cxf:features>
</cxf:bus>
```

When my service outputs a PDF file, I set the Content-Type to `application/pdf`.

It seems the issue comes from `org.apache.cxf.interceptor.AbstractLoggingInterceptor`, which defines a list called BINARY_CONTENT_MEDIA_TYPES that does not consider `application/pdf` to be a binary MIME type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar issue rather implemented in awkward way.

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
import org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingOutInterceptor;
import org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingMessage;

public class KPLogOutInterceptor extends LoggingOutInterceptor {

    @Override
    protected String formatLoggingMessage(LoggingMessage loggingMessage) {

        return removePayload(loggingMessage.toString()); 
    }


    private String removePayload(String str){

        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(str);
        if (str.indexOf("Payload:") + 9 > 8) {
            builder.setLength(builder.indexOf("Payload:") + 8);
            builder.append(" <content skipped>\n");
            builder.append(StringUtils.repeat('-', 25));
        }
        return builder.toString();  
    }
}
```

cxf configuration

```
<cxf:bus>
        <cxf:inInterceptors>
            <ref bean="inInterceptor" />
        </cxf:inInterceptors>
        <cxf:outInterceptors>
            <ref bean="outInterceptor" />
        </cxf:outInterceptors>
        <cxf:outFaultInterceptors>
            <ref bean="outInterceptor" />
        </cxf:outFaultInterceptors>
        <cxf:inFaultInterceptors>
            <ref bean="inInterceptor" />
        </cxf:inFaultInterceptors>
</cxf:bus>

<bean id="inInterceptor" class="org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingInInterceptor" />
<bean id="outInterceptor" class="com.kp.KPLogOutInterceptor"></bean>
```

Comment: I have overriden `LoggingOutInterceptor` like you did, and it worked. The only difference is that I have overriden the `isBinaryContent` method instead of the `formatLoggingMessage` method.